Are there any consumer NAS models that support MTP?
Are there any consumer NAS devices that support MTP/PTP over USB for Android? I also need a two-bay device with RAID 1.
By which of course I mean a standalone NAS that supports Samba and has USB ports that an Android phone could be connected too and mounted from inside the NAS OS.
I've always seen Synology as the gold standard for consumer NAS, but my Synology DS216j certainly doesn't support it, and it doesn't seem like their newer models do either.
Are there any models (either from Synology or another brand) that support both MTP and RAID 1?

Kinda stupid, but if it were me, I would probably just run whatever NAS OS I wanted, then have another machine or VM that handles connecting to the Android phone and copying photos to the NAS. Would that work?

Thanks for the reply! Yes, I've considered building my own NAS solution, with something like Ubuntu.  It would work, but I like having the simplicity of a small, all-in-one solution. I eventually reached out to Synology support and they said they would pass it along as a suggestion.

So if you really like Synology, you could use Synology VMM to spin up a Windows/Linux VM and use that to do the USB transfers. Personally, I don't like the amount of paid restrictions that Synology enforces and I'd rather use something open source (you can make some super-small and easy-to-use NASs these days), but if you'd rather stick with Synology it's totally possible.
